# i need to eliminate xmlns property from every element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I dont want to put xmlns property in every element i will add in the grid.
Is there anyway to define it globally ..?

Here my code:

```
 string xaml = "<Grid xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'  
     Name='canvasGrid'>
    <Ellipse xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' />
      <Path xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' /> 
   </Grid>"

 Grid grid = (Grid)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
 panel.Children.Add(grid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you don't need to put it for every control. `Setting on root element(Grid) is sufficient enough.`

Comment: What exception? Post it.

Comment: yeah its working now....i think i tried with the root and also some other element having xmlns tag.

Comment: @TaLhaKhan - Great..!!

Answer (score 0):

The xmlns is defined in the Mainwindow. You can't write a window layout with using the Window tag.